# CouchDB Rewrite Rule to Update Handler result in 405 method not allowed

Tags: curl, couchdb

I have a strange problem. To hide most parts of my request URL I'm using rewrite rules for my view, list and update functions in CouchDB. Everything works fine despite of the short URL for the update function. Without the short URL I can invoke the update function without any problem, but if I use the short URL I get a 405 method not allowed.

With short URL

curl -iX POST -g 'https://[user]:[pw]@[domain]/db_short/update_fields/IndicationSet_1750' -d '{"Comment":"Wwow"}' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H 'Accept: application/json'

```
HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
Server: nginx/1.9.15                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
Date: Wed, 17 Aug 2016 11:57:57 GMT                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
Content-Type: application/json                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
Content-Length: 75                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
Connection: keep-alive                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
Cache-Control: must-revalidate                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
Allow: DELETE,GET,HEAD,PUT
```

Without short URL

curl -iX POST -g 'https://[user]:[pw]@[domain]/futon/kunde_a/_design/update_indicationset_nuel/_update/update_fields/IndicationSet_1750' -d '{"Comment":"Wwowwwww"}' -H 'Content-Type: application/json'

```
HTTP/1.1 201 Created
Server: nginx/1.9.15
Date: Wed, 17 Aug 2016 12:03:47 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 7
Connection: keep-alive
X-Couch-Update-NewRev: 18-6d5bba9e51bf4d28b672776c4bce11d1
X-Couch-Id: IndicationSet_1750
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000
```

In my configuration i have enabled cors with all necessary settings

cors
credentials: true
headers: accept, authorization, content-type, origin, refers, x-csrf-token
methods: GET, PUT, POST, HEAD, DELETE
origins: *

httpd
enable_cors: true

Answer (score 1):

The "short URL" is incorrect. As the [documentation](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/1.6.1/api/ddoc/rewrites.html) says, the pattern for rewrite URLs is:

> ANY /{db}/_design/{ddoc}/_rewrite/{path}

In your case, this URL should be working:

```
https://[user]:[pw]@[domain]/db_short/_design/update_indicationset_nuel/_rewrite/update_fields/IndicationSet_1750
```

Comment: Hey, thx for your response. The answer was a little bit easier. I forgot to add a wildcard to the rewrite rule of my update function to handle the document id.

Comment: Ok, so I guess you are also using a vhosts configuration (http://docs.couchdb.org/en/1.6.1/config/http.html#virtual-hosts), if you are able to omit the "_design/..." part of the URL.

Answer (score 0):

After some digging I found the problem. I forgot to add a wildcard to the rewrite rule for my update function to handle the document id at the end of the query path.

Old version:

```
{
       "from": "/update_fields/",
       "to": "/../update_indicationset_nuel/_update/update_fields/",
       "method": "*"
   }
```

New version:

```
{
       "from": "/update_fields/*",
       "to": "/../update_indicationset_nuel/_update/update_fields/*",
       "method": "*"
   }
```